# What is wrong with my Della Porta cipher code?

Tags: java, for-loop, cryptography, iteration

I am currently working on a programming project involving the Della Porta Cipher. My `EncryptMessage` method seems to be getting hung up when it encounters a space in the user input. If I remove all the spaces from the user message, the program encodes the message correctly, but leaves the spaces out. I need the spaces, and I'm stuck on how to reintroduce them back into the `convertedMessage` string before I print it out.

Also, I need my key to iterate over the top of the user message in the output, so the user can see which character of the key is affecting which character letter in the user message.

My current code:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PortaCypher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter message: ");
        String message = input.nextLine();
        char[] messageArray = message.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray(); //getting rid of spaces gives the right encryption, minus the needed spaces
        System.out.print("enter keyword: ");
        String key = input.nextLine();
        char[] keyArray = key.toLowerCase().replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray();
        String convertedMessage = String.valueOf(encryptMessage(messageArray, keyArray));

        //final output
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(getKeyString(keyArray).toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(message.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(convertedMessage.toUpperCase());

    }

    public static char[] encryptMessage(char[] messageArray, char[] keyArray) {
        char[] convertedMessage = new char[messageArray.length];

        for (int x = 0, y = 0; x < messageArray.length; x++) {
            char characterOfMessage = messageArray[x];
            char characterOfKey = keyArray[(y % keyArray.length)];

            if (characterOfMessage == ' ') {
                convertedMessage[x] = ' ';
                y = -1;  //resets characterOfKey to the beginning character of the key after seeing a space
            }
            else convertedMessage[x] = portaCypherTableau[(((int)characterOfKey)-97) / 2][((int)characterOfMessage)-97]; y++;


        }   return convertedMessage;
    }



    public static String getKeyString(char[] keyArray){
        String finalKey = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.length; i++) { finalKey = finalKey + (keyArray[i]); }
        return finalKey;
    }

    public static String getMessageString(char[] messageArray){
        String finalMessage = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < messageArray.length; i++) { finalMessage = finalMessage + (messageArray[i]); }
        return finalMessage;
    }


    //                                                    Keys        a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    l    m    m    o    p    q    r    s    t    u    v    w    x    y    z
    public static final char  portaCypherTableau[][] = /* A,B */   {{'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm' },
                                                       /* C,D */    {'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l' },
                                                       /* E,F */    {'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k' },
                                                       /* G,H */    {'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' },
                                                       /* I,G */    {'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i' },
                                                       /* K,L */    {'s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' },
                                                       /* M,N */    {'t', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' },
                                                       /* O,P */    {'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' },
                                                       /* Q,R */    {'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' },
                                                       /* S,T */    {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' },
                                                       /* U,V */    {'x', 'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b', 'c' },
                                                       /* W,X */    {'y', 'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a', 'b' },
                                                       /* Y,Z */    {'z', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'a' }};
}
```

Correct output would look like:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but it prints spaces when I try it out. What gives? What have you tried with regards to the key?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I worked on it some more and figured out that it was a simple bracketing error and some error with my logic.  I need to include y++ in the else portion of my encryptMessage method, rather than y = -1.   To get the iteration of the key over the message, I ended up creating a for loop in my main method to print out the key character-by-character, and skip over index positions occupied by spaces.